# Atom editor setting format to make [property-key] inside tag become italic

Tags: editor, atom-editor, gedit

I've used atom recently when i watched some videos and saw that the `property-key` in html tag in italic form. But it's not my case, so are there any setting to turn on italic `property-key` in atom or gedit editor?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Stylesheet config file of Atom in File -> Stylesheet... and add this at the end of this file would work.

```
atom-text-editor::shadow{
    .entity.other.attribute-name {
        font-style: italic;
    }
}
```

reference: https://miklb.com/customizing-atom-editor/